# How to list all computers in the ActiveDirectory with their OU in a tables?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I was wondering if it is possible to list all computers in the Active Directory with their OU name?  Something like this:

```
Name  |        OU         |
---------------------------  
WS1   |  Administratrion  |
WS2   |  Finances         |
WS3   |  IT               |
```

The best I could come up with is this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * | FT Name,DistinguishedName -a
```

which produces the following output:

```
Name  |                     OU                      |
-----------------------------------------------------
WS1   |  CN=WS1,OU=Administratrion, DC=test, DC=nl  |
WS2   |  CN=WS1,OU=Finances, DC=test, DC=nl         |
WS3   |  CN=WS1,OU=IT, DC=test, DC=nl               |
```

But that's not exactly what I want.

Comment: You know, the voting patterns here on SO never cease to amaze me. On the one hand you have zero-effort write-code-for-me questions receiving two or more upvotes. On the other hand you have questions like this, which (albeit poorly formatted) ask a reasonably answerable question, clearly describe what they want to achieve (with actual examples), *and* show at least *some* research effort. And get downvoted for it. *\*shakes head\**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the common name portion of the distinguished name, then look up the OU:

```
Get-ADComputer  -Filter * |
  Select-Object Name, @{n='OU';e={
    $_.DistinguishedName -replace '^cn=.*?,(ou=.*)', '$1' |
      Get-ADOrganizationalUnit | Select-Object -Expand Name
  }} |
  Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser.

Comment: But could you explain what the script does?

Comment: Like I said: it removes the common name part (`CN=WS1,`) from the computer's distinguished name (leaving the distinguished name of the OU), then looks up that OU and expands its name. I'm using a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to add that OU name as a property to the output objects before formatting them as a table.